# expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 40882, but received input with shape (None, 1)

Tags: python, neural-network

I have this `train` and `test` set:

```
[1] Y=count_text['emotion']
[2] x=count_text['word_count']
[3] X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test= train_test_split(x,Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=np.random)
```

If I want to see the `X_train` and `y_train` `shape` I can use:

```
[4] print(str(X_train.shape)+''+str(y_train.shape)):
```

And the output will be:

`(40882,)(40882,)`

When I run this part of the code:

```
[5] from keras.models import Sequential
[6] from keras import layers

[7] input_dim = (X_train.shape[0])  # Number of features

[8] model = Sequential()
[9] model.add(layers.Dense(10, input_dim=input_dim, activation='relu'))
[10] model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
[11] model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
[12] model.summary()
```

I have this:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 dense (Dense)               (None, 10)                408830    
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 11        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 408,841
Trainable params: 408,841
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

But when I run this part of the code:

```
[13] history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, verbose=False, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), batch_size=10)
```

I have an error:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential" "                 f"(type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 40882, but received input with shape (None, 1)
    
    Call arguments received by layer "sequential" "                 f"(type Sequential):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 1), dtype=int64)
      • training=True
      • mask=None
```

I tried using this after [3] and before [4] to fix the problem:

```
[3.1] X_train = X_train.values.reshape(-1,1)
[3.2] X_test = X_test.values.reshape(-1,1)
```

And [7] would be:

```
[7] input_dim = (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1])
```

But now in [9] I have an error:

```
[9] model.add(layers.Dense(10, input_dim=input_dim, activation='relu'))

Error: TypeError: Dimension value must be integer or None or have an __index__ method, got value '(40882, 1)' with type '<class 'tuple'>'
```

How can I solve the error in the dimensions?